# If a character is woken up by an ally during combat, when is their next action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, actions, initiative

When a character is awoken after being affected by a Sleep spell (or any other of the various ways to give an adventurer extra Zzz's), when do they act?

- Have they been 'delaying' initiative until that point? Does it matter if they would have acted already?
- Do they have to wait until they get another turn, even if they *would* have acted immediately before the ally that woke them up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When a character is awoken after being it by Sleep (or any other of the various ways to give an adventurer extra Zzz's), when do they act?

In normal initiative order

> Have they been 'delaying' initiative until that point?

No. They haven't been able to take actions, so they can't delay.

> Does it matter if they would have acted already?

No. If their ally didn't wake them up before their turn, then they have missed it.

> Do they have to wait until they get another turn, even if they would have acted immediately before the ally that woke them up?

Yes

Comment: While this is correct, it would be useful to cite the rules at some point to prove it.

Comment: I agree with @Ladifas. This is always how I've seen it played, but that's not based on any rules that I could find. I'm really looking for something (rule I missed, eratta, FAQ, etc) from WotC/Paizo. I'd accept proof from 3.5 if Paizo didn't put it anywhere.

Comment: @Ladifas you don't need a specific rules citation here because the answer above is simply the "default" handling of initiative. There are no rules saying you do anything weird to initiative if someone is unconscious, so initiative remains exactly the same.

Comment: It's difficult to provide a reference because you are asking for proof of a negative. I can't show you where Paizo **didn't** write that being woken up changes initiative.

Comment: No initiative penalties for lack of coffee, either. More to the point though, remember that they will begin prone and therefore you'll need to take that into account on their first action.

Comment: @CM_Dayton I kind of addressed that in another question, asking if there were rules for a way to 'pick up' another character from prone. The best we could come up with was 'lift a heavy object' (Standard action that provokes). Regardless, that's not the question at hand. What's to say a sleeping character doesn't get to Delay their Initiative until another character wakes them up?

Comment: I'd rather not accept an answer because "that's the way it is". However, if we continue to not put forth a reason you can't Delay (or something), I'll begrudgingly do so.

Comment: @Ifusaso — As I said in the answer, you can't Delay because Delaying is an action and you can't take actions when unconscious.

Comment: But a target isn't [Unconscious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Unconscious), but they are [Helpless](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Helpless) which doesn't prevent you from taking actions (as the case with being bound, you can still Escape Artist etc).

Comment: OK, they don't have the Unconscious condition. They are however, *asleep*. They can't take actions even if that isn't spelt out explicitly.