# Can you delay action while unconscious?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, initiative, unconscious

Suppose my character in PF1 is unconscious and dying, and the party cleric's turn is not until after mine in the initiative round. I would like to avoid wasting a turn by delaying until after the cleric's turn. This way, the cleric can heal my character and he can get back up immediately if he heals above 0 HP. My understanding of the rules for dying is that I would still need to make my check to stabilize, but that is *not* what I am trying to avoid here, I'm only asking about **whether I can delay at all**.

Is it possible to save my action economy this way? I know that you can't take any actions while you're unconscious, but is delaying your turn considered an action or not? The entry seems to imply that it is not.

> By choosing to delay, you take no action and then act normally on whatever initiative count you decide to act.

Is there a more definitive ruling on this anywhere?

Comment: Directly [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94319/if-a-character-is-woken-up-by-an-ally-during-combat-when-is-their-next-action)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It isn't exactly clear, but the implication is that you cannot delay when unconscious.

1. The section is titled [Special Initiative *Actions*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#Special_Initiative_Actions), and you cannot take "actions" while [Dying](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Dying)
2. "You" must make the choice to delay, something your character is (probably) incapable of doing while unconscious

   > By **choosing** to delay... you **decide** to act... waiting to see what's going to happen...

Comment: This interpretation seems in direct conflict with the part of the Delay entry originally quoted ("you *take no action*"). Are you saying that the entry is just poorly worded but correctly labeled?

Comment: I'm saying Delaying is a form of action (albeit inaction), not simply not acting. It is poorly worded, however (hence "It isn't exactly clear"). I was originally going to cite that they fixed it in 2e (possibly showing intent as a sub-point), but I also could not find clear wording in the new edition.